# Is there another adjective for the mind other than mental which does not have negative connotations?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

If I want to describe someone who has a great mind, or great mentality, describing him as a mental giant doesn't just seem right. Even though there isn't a comma between mental & giant, it may be misunderstood as calling someone mental & a giant.

Is there a better adjective which can be used here?

Comment: "Mental giant" is understood to be referring to exceptional intelligence, but the problem is the expression is often used sarcastically. So I would not use it, but not for the reason you gave.

Comment: Intellectual giant?

Comment: Creative shouldn't be a bad option.

Comment: But, are the words, mental giant, or intellectual always positive?  Even 'creative' is not. Since '...without negative connotations' is quite relative, it may be difficult to answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatives for *mental* in the sense of relating to the brain and mental capabilities would include:

- an *intellectual* giant
- a *cognitive* giant (this is a bit weird)
- a *cerebral* giant

but you're probably better of going with the other suggestions and ditching *giant* for something that better matches what you're aiming at.

Comment: I like Cerebral Giant.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me the problem is the noun "giant."
If you're emphasizing the mental capability, then make that concept the noun and modify accordingly.
Some examples:

- Brilliant mind (simple phasing, often the best way to go)
- Gigantic brain (adhering to the original as much as possible)
- Deep intellect (similar to "towering intellect," a cliché, which can be understood as sarcastic)
- Cognitive wizard (emphasizes the magical)
- Perspicacious frontal lobe (ok, now I've gone too far)